# How to retrieve from one array using the value in another array javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array named `x` like below.

```js
x = [
  { id: 1, content: 'abc' },
  { id: 2, content: 'cde' },
  { id: 3, content: 'xyz' }
]
```

I have another array `y` like this.

```js
y = [1, 3]
```

I want to fetch all data from `x` by mapping the id of `x` to the values in `y`.
So my output will be like below.

```js
[
  { content: 'abc' },
  { content: 'xyz' }
]
```

How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array.filter` (+ some to comare with other array) along with `array.map`

```js
let x=[
{id: 1, content:'abc'},
{id: 2, content:'cde'},
{id: 3, content:'xyz'}];

let y=[1,3];

let result = x.filter(obj => y.some(yy => yy === obj.id)).map(({content}) => ({content}));
console.log(result);

//or
let result2 = x.filter(obj => y.some(yy => yy === obj.id)).map(x => x.content);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Got it. thanks. :) And mickl, suppose I want only values, is there any way to format this query. I mean only {abc,"xyz"} as output

Comment: Like `.map(x => x.content);` ?

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks mickl :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Array.filter() and Array.map() you can get the results.

Suppose:

```
const x = [
  {id: 1, content:'abc'},
  {id: 2, content:'cde'},
  {id: 3, content:'xyz'},
];

const y = [1,3];

const result = x.filter(item => y.includes(item.id)).map(item => {
    return {
        content: item.content
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
{content:'abc'}
{content:'xyz'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array reduce for that:

```js
const x = [ { id: 1, content: 'abc' } 
          , { id: 2, content: 'cde' } 
          , { id: 3, content: 'xyz' } 
          ] 
const y = [ 1, 3 ]

const result = x.reduce((a,{id,content})=> {
                  if (y.some(eY=>eY=== id)) a.push({ content } ) 
                  return a
                },[])
          

console.log( result )
```

Answer (score 0):

A for-loop can be used to extract elements with matching IDs.

**Here is a working demo using a for loop:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Find elements</button>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <script>
            var x = [
                {id: 1, content:'abc'},
                {id: 2, content:'cde'},
                {id: 3, content:'xyz'}
            ]

            var y = [1, 3]
            var result = []

            function myFunction() {
                for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    if( y.indexOf(x[i].id) >= 0 ) {
                        // Add content of matching elements to result array
                        result.push(x[i].content)
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]